# jQuery selector after dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an dynamically created element using a jQuery selector but it is returning an empty array.

The first thing I am doing is grabbing an empty div:

```
var packDiv = document.getElementById('templates');
packDiv.innerHTML = "";
```

then adding items to it in a loop:

```
packDiv.innerHTML = packDiv.innerHTML + "<img id='" + thumbName + "' src='thumbs/" + thumbName + "'/>";
```

after the loop finishes I try to select an item using:

```
console.log($("#"+thumbName));
```

and it returns the empty array. All the things I search on show to use `.on` but all the examples show that is to set event handlers.

My question is how do I format a selector for dynamically created elements?

Comment: What does `console.log(packDiv.innerHTML)` produce after all items are added?

Comment: Problem lies outside of the snippet you have provided; http://jsfiddle.net/pzz9A/

Comment: @SalmanA it shows the expected data.

Comment: Well I am sure `console.log("#"+thumbName);` also returns something expected.

Comment: If you are using jQuery you might as well use it from the start eg $('#templates').html()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `thumbName` is a file name, for example `foo.jpg`, it would not be parsed by jQuery as you would expect. `.jpg` part of the name is treated as a class name, and since you are not providing this class name for that element, jQuery returns an empty array - it does not find anything matching your selector. You are actually searching for an element with id `foo` and class name `jpg`.

The way I would go with this is something along these lines:

```
var packDiv = $('#templates');
packDiv.empty();

//inside a loop
packDiv.append("<img class='" + thumbName.replace(/\./g,'') + "' src='thumbs/" + thumbName + "'/>");

console.log($("."+thumbName.replace(/\./g,'')));
```

Comment: I would use a regex to match all the dots in the replace function : `replace(/\./g,'')`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code. Old version will only replace the first dot it finds.

Comment: I totally forgot that it was the whole filename. It was thinking jpg was a class. Thank you!